# How to run Google Maps application in Beagle board Eclair?

Tags: android, beagleboard

I have an Android Google Maps application created under the platform Google AP1s 2.1 update API level 7. When I push/copy the application to Beagle Board (having Android 2.1 update1 API level 7), I can't see the application in the system/app folder. Why it is behaving like this?. Do I need to add some jar?

Answer (score 0):

Your Beagle Board won't have the maps.jar that's necessary for such an application to install.
It will behave in the same way as if you tried to install it on an emulator with just an Android 2.1 target compared to a Google APIS 2.1 target.

I'm not familiar with the Beagle Board but I believe it should be possible to pull the jar from the system/framework folder on a Google emulator and transfer it to the Beagle Board.

You should check that this is within the terms of the Google licence agreement though. As the Beagle Board is an educational tool and not a commercial product, I'd say it was at least within the spirit of the agreement.

Comment: I added maps.jar to system/framework folder. Still it is missing some shared library. While I try to install the app using adb install, it shows INSTALLATION FAILED, MISSING SHARED LIBRARY error

Comment: If you have <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> in your manifest then try removing it. That way it should at least install and launch. It might crash at runtime though, but it would be step further on.

Comment: Thanks Nick, now I could install the app. But when I clicks it, it crashes